# what is the etymology of "Nebat"?

Tags: hebrew, names, historical-figures, etymology, navi-prophets

[Brown Driver Briggs](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5028.htm), usually unabashed at offering extra-canonical etymology, offers only "proper name" as the etymological parse of נבט, given that it is only ever found in the phrase " יָרָבְעָ֣ם בֶּן-נְבָ֔ט  ‏" What is the etymology of this Biblical name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look or regard.

See: [A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the Hebrew Language for Readers of English](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/965220093X) p. 401, 1987 by [R. Ernest Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Klein)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps seeng or looking. See [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43656&st=&pgnum=209&hilite=) on Radak and R. Yona Ibn G'anach [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36864&st=&pgnum=322)